# does debug level INFO also show error too? django

Tags: python, django, debugging, logging

I have such `LOGGING` setup for my django, but I realized using `DEBUG` level, it shows TOO much especially the template `variableDoesNotExist` `debug` is quite annoying.

I have this as my current setup

```
LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': False,
'formatters': {
    'simple_time': {
        # simple_time, that just outputs the log level name (e.g., DEBUG) plus time and the log message.
        'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(message)s'
    },
},
'handlers': {
    'debug_file': {
        'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
        'filename': os.path.join(BASE_DIR) + '/debug.log',
        'formatter': 'simple_time'
    },
},
'loggers': {
    'django': {
        'handlers': ['debug_file'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'propagate': True,
    },
},
```

}

I am wondering if I change the `level` to `INFO` will it just show `INFO` and not show `ERROR` level if any?

Else, is it possible to split different levels into different files?

I tried something like this, but not sure if it'll work properly

```
'handlers': {
    'debug_file': {
        'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
        'filename': os.path.join(BASE_DIR) + '/debug.log',
        'formatter': 'simple_time'
    },
    'info_file': {
        'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
        'filename': os.path.join(BASE_DIR) + '/info.log',
        'formatter': 'simple_time'
    },
},
'loggers': {
    'django_debug': {
        'handlers': ['debug_file'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'propagate': True,
    },
    'django_info': {
        'handlers': ['info_file'],
        'level': 'INFO',
        'propagate': True,
    },
},
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions

Answer (score 2):

Setting a log level always means to show anything at that level or higher.

As you can see from [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging-levels), ERROR is higher than INFO, so setting the level to INFO will show both - as well as WARNING and CRITICAL, which is the highest level.

However, you certainly can set up two different loggers for different levels.

Comment: thanks a lot but then as the bottom of my post, is that how I can set up different logger on different levels? I set it up but not sure what I can do to make the error happen so I can check if it's done properly